# Collapse a nested dict into a list of dicts in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an input nested dict as follows:

```
{'name': 'Mark', 'marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}
```

The output i am expecting is as follows:

```
[{'name': 'Mark', 'english':23, 'maths':35}, {{'name': 'Mark', 'english':50, 'maths':55}]
```

My code is as follows:

```
In [22]: input = {'name': 'Mark', 'marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}

In [23]: marks = input.pop('marks')

In [24]: output = []

In [25]: for mark in marks:
    ...:     output.append({**input, **mark})
...:

In [26]: output
Out[26]:
[{'english': 20, 'maths': 25, 'name': 'Mark'},
 {'english': 50, 'maths': 55, 'name': 'Mark'}]
```

Works as expected.However, this works only for python 3.5 and above since **{**x, **y}** to merge 2 dicts was only introduced from that version on.

Also my dataset is huge and I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to achieve this.What is the is best way to achieve this python 2.7. I am also open to using external libraries like `Pandas` and `numpy`.

Comment: What does your data look like when there is more than one entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution using `pandas` :

```
import pandas as pd

x = {'name': 'Mark', 'marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}

x = pd.DataFrame(x)
x = pd.concat([x['name'],x['marks'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

print(x.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Output:

```
[{'english': 20, 'name': 'Mark', 'maths': 25}, 
 {'english': 50, 'name': 'Mark', 'maths': 55}]
```

*PS: tested on python3 but it should work on python2.7 as well*

**Edit**

*More generic solution with additional key*
Now you don't have to hardcode the other keys.

```
x = {'name': 'Mark', 'add':'Mum','marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}


x = pd.DataFrame(x)
cols = list(x.columns)  
cols.remove('marks')  # to get columns except `mark`

x = pd.concat([x[cols],x['marks'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(x.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Comment: this looks really promising..the only issue is that while the 'marks' key always has the same name..the 'name' key can change and hence my solution does not rely on the key 'name'..can the pandas solution be altered so that it does not depend on the 'name' key ?

Comment: Perfect..one final thing..how do i store the final output in a variable rather than printing it ?

Comment: @Amistad assign it back like  `x = x.to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simple list comprehension though with dirty hack to return the result:

```
input = {'name': 'Mark', 'marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}

marks_list = input.pop('marks')
output = [marks.update(input) or marks for marks in marks_list]

[{'name': 'Mark', 'maths': 25, 'english': 20}, {'name': 'Mark', 'maths': 55, 'english': 50}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pydash (https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it supports python 2.7:

```
from pydash import py_ as _
inputs = {'name': 'Mark', 'marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}

def construct_dict(d1, d2):
   d1.update(d2)
   return d1

_(inputs['marks']).map(lambda x: construct_dict({ 'name': inputs['name'] }, x)).value()

# output
[{'maths': 25, 'name': 'Mark', 'english': 20}, {'maths': 55, 'name': 'Mark', 'english': 50}]
```

Answer (score 0):

in python2.7 i would do the following:

```
input = {'name': 'Mark', 'marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}

marks = input.pop('marks')
output =  map(lambda x:dict(input, **x), marks)
```

Answer (score 0):

With python 2.7:

```
idict =  {'name': 'Mark', 'marks':[{'english':20, 'maths':25},{'english':50, 'maths':55}]}
print (idict)
marks = idict.pop("marks")
result = []
for each in marks:
    result.append({'name': idict['name']})
    for key, val in each.items():
        result[-1][key] = val
print (result)

{'name': 'Mark', 'marks': [{'maths': 25, 'english': 20}, {'maths': 55, 'english': 50}]}
[{'maths': 25, 'name': 'Mark', 'english': 20}, {'maths': 55, 'name': 'Mark', 'english': 50}]
```